# Prevent implicit conversion of constructor arguments to external library type

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, constructor, implicit-conversion

Consider the following code:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

typedef boost::iterator_range<boost::counting_iterator<int>> int_range;

template <typename T>
class Ref {
    T* p_;    
  public:    
    Ref(T* p) : p_(p) { }
    /* possibly other implicit conversion constructors,
       but no unconstrained template constructors that don't
       use the explicit keyword... */  
    operator T*() const { return p_; }
    operator const T*() const { return p_; }    
};

struct Bar { };

class Foo {    
  public:    
    Foo(int a, char b) { /* ... */ }    
    Foo(int a, const Ref<Bar>& b) { /* ... */ }     
    Foo(int a, const int_range& r) { /* ... */ }     
};

int main() {
  Bar b;
  Foo f(5, &b);
  return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't compile because the use of the `Foo` constructor is ambiguous, since `boost::iterator_range` apparently has a templated constructor that takes a single argument and is not declared as `explicit`.  Assuming that changing the structure of `Ref` is not an option, how can I fix this problem?  I came up with the following possible solution, but it's ugly and not easily maintainable, especially if there are more than a few constructors of `Foo`:

```
template<typename range_like>
Foo(
  int a, 
  const range_like& r,
  typename std::enable_if<
    not std::is_convertible<range_like, Ref<Bar>>::value
      and std::is_convertible<range_like, int_range>::value,
    bool
  >::type unused = false
) { /* ... */ }
```

or similarly

```
template<typename range_like>
Foo(
  int a, 
  const range_like& r,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<typename std::decay<range_like>::type, int_range>::value,
    bool
  >::type unused = false
) { /* ... */ }
```

which has the disadvantage that all other implicit type conversion for `int_range` is disabled, and thus relies on unspecified features of `boost` (and my instincts tell me it's probably a bad idea anyway).  Is there a better way to do this?  (C++14 "concepts-lite" aside, which is really what this problem wants I think).

Comment: Add a `Foo(int, Bar*)` constructor, perhaps?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Nice thought, but that doesn't solve the more general problem that I'm trying to get at here.  It's more a problem with the simplicity of the example than an actual solution.

Comment: How about an example that actually demonstrates this more general problem that you are trying to get at?

Comment: report a bug to boost?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This example works fine.  Suppose there are other things that can be cast to a `Ref<Bar>`.  Not an unlimited number of things, as with the templated constructor, but something more than just a pointer to `Bar`.  I'll add a `/* ... */` to the `Ref` class to indicate this.

Comment: @DarioOO That's what I thought, but I don't think my C++ was good enough to tell the boost developers that they're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this program is a minimal example of your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

struct T {};

struct A {
  A(T) {}
};

struct B {
  B(T) {}
};

struct C {
  C(A const&) { std::cout << "C(A)\n"; }
  C(B const&) { std::cout << "C(B)\n"; }
};

int main() {
  C c{T{}};
}
```

You have two types `A` and `B` both implicitly convertible from another type `T`, and another type `C` implicitly convertible from `A` and `B`, but for which implicit conversion from `T` is ambiguous. You desire to disambiguate the situation so that `C` is implicitly convertible from `T` using the sequence of conversions `T => A => C`, but you must do so without changing the definitions of `A` and `B`.

The obvious solution - already suggested in the comments - is to introduce a third converting constructor for `C`: `C(T value) : C(A(value)) {}`. You have rejected this solution as not general enough, but without clarifying what the "general" problem is.

I conjecture that the more general problem you want solved is to make `C` unambiguously implicitly convertible from *any* type `U` that is implicitly convertible to `A` using the sequence of conversions `U => A => C`. This is achievable by introducing an additional template constructor to `C` ([Live code demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c80f41e601452eb)):

```
template <typename U, typename=typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_base_of<A,typename std::decay<U>::type>::value &&
   std::is_convertible<U&&, A>::value>::type>
C(U&& u) : C(A{std::forward<U>(u)}) {}
```

The template constructor is a direct match for `C(U)`, and so is unambiguously preferred over the `C(A)` and `C(B)` constructors that would require a conversion. It is constrained to accept only types `U` such that

- `U` is convertible to `A` (for obvious reasons)
- `U` is *not* `A` or a reference to `A` or a type derived from `A`, to avoid ambiguity with the `C(const A&)` constructor and infinite recursion in the case that `U` is e.g. `A&` or `A&&`.

Notably this solution does not require changing the definitions of `T`, `A`, `B`, `C(A const&)` or `C(B const&)`, so it is nicely self-contained.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you propose the second solution?  (with the important modification that you've used `is_base_of` rather than `is_same`)

Comment: @DavidHollman Not exactly. Your second solution accepts only the type `const int_range&`, effectively disabling implicit conversions to `int_range` (as you mention in the OP). My solution adds a new constructor that is a better match for anything convertible to `A` (`Ref<Bar>`) than the pre-existing constructors that require conversion. [It would translate into your concrete example like this.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b711c5de5e88b20 "Live code at Coliru")